# openpyxl paste collected list in specific range?

Tags: python, openpyxl

First: I just started with python. And spefically with openpyxl. 
So I went ahead and tried this code out:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('E:/Python36/Test/sample.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet']

#get all values, without knowing the row and column dimension - possible?

myRange = []
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=9, max_row=13, min_col=9, max_col=11):
    rowList = []
    for cell in row:
        rowList.append(cell.value)
    myRange.append(rowList)

targetRange = ws.iter_rows()

#paste all values, in specific range on new sheet or new wb? how?

wb.create_sheet('Sheet2')
ws = wb['Sheet2']

for i, j in zip(targetRange, myRange):
    for a, b in zip(i, j):
        a.value = b

wb.save('E:/Python36/Test/exa.xlsx')
```

And now I'm stuck :) 
My questions are:

1) I can't figure out how to get all cell values on a sheet, without knowing the row and column dimensions on fore hand - is this possible?

2) I want to paste all the found values (range) in a (other) specific workbook sheet beginning in row 4 column 4.

TiA!